# What scanf return if it can't get the right literals characters?

Tags: c

what scanf return in the flowing  situations ?

`scanf("the number is : %d", &n) ;`
and the stdin contain :  `number is 5`

`scanf("%d is the number", &n) ;`
and the stdin contain :  `5 the number`

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just try it out instead of posting a question here?

Comment: That's right but i can't because i havn't any app that simulate and ide on my phone.

Comment: It helps to have a PC/mac laptop to do programming. There are some attachments to get keyboard/mouse H/W for a tablet (i.e. via the USB plug or bluetooth). Although somewhat painful on a phone/tablet, there are online, web based IDEs that you can use. I've never used one myself [except for phone interviews], but search web on "web based IDE". One link from that: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/programmer-browser-ides/ If you _have_ a laptop and want to develop apps for [android] phones, Google has "Android Studio"

Answer (score 1):

The first example will return `0` and not update `n`. It needs the input to start with `the`, and that fails, so it never gets past that,.

The second example will return `1` and set `n` to `5`. The `5` at the beginning of the input matches the `%d` format, so it's filled in. The rest of the input doesn't match, but it has already parsed the number, so it doesn't change the return value. The rest of the input will be left in the buffer, to be processed by the next call to `scanf()`.